# Component wont re-render when changes happens to redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I have problems with using Redux saga with react hooks. It clearly states that useSelector() will subscribe to the Redux store, and run the selector whenever an action is dispatched.

here is the component im trying to update:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector} from "react-redux";

const InfoPage = () => {
    const summoner = useSelector(state => state.summoner);
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.loading);
    console.log(loading,summoner) {*/Both undefined and only gets called once*/}
    if(!summoner){
       return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return( 
        <div>
           {summoner.name}
        </div>
    )
}

export default InfoPage;
```

The component gets called via a history.push('/infopage') when I dispatch the action to fetch the "summoner", which again dispatches another action when successfully managing to fetch summoner. This should rerender my InfoPage if i understand this right.

My redux store has the values after the fetch, but the InfoPage won't rerender, heres the last state:

[image: Picture of my redux store]

heres also my reducer

[image: reducer]

Comment: Do you have a sandbox demo?

Comment: No, don't realy know how to do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem... I've forgot that my saga reducer is called "saga" when exporting it. so to fix this problem i had to change:

```
 const summoner = useSelector(state => state.summoner);
```

to

```
 const summoner = useSelector(state => state.saga.summoner);
```